# Any tutorials add a new robot to ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
Our lab just received a videoray Pro 4 (underwater robot). But all the software are offered in Windows. Our leader want to implement this robot using ROS in linux.
Any ideas or suggestions how to deploy it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202684/any-tutorials-add-a-new-robot-to-ros/) by [Tixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20747/tixiao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2015-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you watch @mwise 's talk from ROSCon 2013 on ROSifying Robots

http://roscon.ros.org/2013/?page_id=14

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3